# ul li column overlap [html and css]

Tags: html, css

I use `<ul>` tag and `<li>` tag for list my data:

```css
ul.listbook{
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

ul.listbook li{

}
```

```html
<ul class="listbook">
  <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbb</li>
  <li>ccccccc</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Result is :
[image: coloum overlap]

The word in first child is overlap column two. 
How do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `word-wrap: break-word` will solve wrapping problem.

```css
ul.listbook{
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

ul.listbook li{
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listbook">
    <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
    <li>bbbbbb</li>
    <li>ccccccc</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

> **word-wrap: break-word**
>
> Indicates that normally unbreakable words may be broken at
>   arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in
>   the line.

Reference: [word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Answer (score 1):

Use `word-wrap: break-word` for this:

```
ul.listbook li {
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

css

```
ul.listbook li{
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut the word instead of breaking, use this:

```
ul.listbook li{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```